# Match a specific string that is a substring of a another string

Tags: regex

I have the following code

```
// the values for the input and the pattern 
// are combinations of R, NR and HR
var input = "NR|HR"; 
var pattern = "R";

var isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

this returns `true` because `NR and HR` contains an `R`

Is there some way I can do an exact match for `R`  with Regular Expressions?

Comment: Do you actually require regular expression? Why don't you simply do `var containsR = input.Split('|').Contains('R')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use word boundaries:

```
var pattern = "\bR\b";
```

Answer (score 0):

Start of string ^ and End of string $

var pattern = "^R$";

Comment: doesn't handle `R|HR` though

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
'(^R\|)|(\|R$)|(\|R\|)|(^R$)'
```

It picks our R
from the following

```
R|NR
NR|R
R
```

but not the following

```
HR|NR
HR
```